# Cordova InAppBrowser _self target not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I need to open some urls in my app via inAppBrowser, the following is the sample code I use:

```
var url = "http://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ハングル"
var target = "_self";    
var options = "location=yes,hidden=no";

var inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

This doesn't work with Cordova v6.3.1, no logs appear in console and it just do nothing.

However this works with Cordova v5.4.0, also if I change target to `_blank` it works properly for all versions.

Does anyone know how to make `_self` target work for Cordova v.6.3.1?

Thanks

Comment: did u figure it out?